# MVC Project not present in Visual Studio Express

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-express

I just installed Visual Studio 2010 Express via Web Platform.
I forgot to install MVC 1.0, so i just downloaded it, and installed.

Go til File -> New Project -> And there is no MVC project Just ASP.NET Web Application and some other stuff.

I then downloaded MVC 2.0, and the same happend. In Control Panel -> Add/Remove Programs, both is installed.

Have you any ideas what this could be?

Answer (score 0):

Use MS Web platform installer to install Asp.Net MVC 2.0.

http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

Comment: I Just did.. But still not present

Comment: Worked for me. I installed it from http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

Answer (score 0):

(super-late response, but maybe it will help somebody else)

Which version of Visual Studio 2010 Express did you install? http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express

AFAIK, the Web projects will only be available if you've installed and are running Visual Web Developer 2010 (i.e. Visual C# 2010 Express is only for client development). I believe this is just a constraint of the Express editions (VS Professional, etc, would behave as you seem to expect).